# Passing closure to be called later

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an array of custom Action objects, each of which has a closure which can be called later. What am I doing wrong here? How can I run the closure?

```
let actionOne = Action(title: "1", image: "blue") {
            println("1 blue")
}

let actionTwo = Action(title: "2", image: "yellow") {
            println("2 yellow")
}


var actions: Array<Action> = [actionOne, actionTwo]


// how to run the closure from actionOne?
actionOne.closure() // compile error: invalid use of '()' to call a value of a non-function type '()?'



-----

class Action {

    var title: String?
    var image: String?
    var closure: ()?

    init(title: String, image: String, closure: () -> ())  {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.closure = closure()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of OptionAction

Comment: updated. should have been Action

Comment: I guess the problem is that `var closure` is optional. Make it non optional ...

Comment: Also you need to store the closure, not the result of invoking it... I'll write an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Action {

    let title: String
    let image: String
    let closure: () -> ()

    init(title: String, image: String, closure: () -> ())  {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.closure = closure
    }
}

let actionOne = Action(title: "1", image: "blue") {
    println("1 blue")
}

let actionTwo = Action(title: "2", image: "yellow") {
    println("2 yellow")
}


var actions: Array<Action> = [actionOne, actionTwo]


actionOne.closure()
```